# Web service: Ruby on Rails versus WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services, programming-languages

I would like to setup a web service, to be accessed via a mobile device. The main purpose of the server is data storage. I would like to know some of your opinions on the advantages\disadvantages between RoR and WCF for building the server-side of the web service.

Comment: That's comparing apples to a hammer - WCF is a communications framework, while RoR is a web-site building toolkit.

Comment: I'm voting to close. This is not a real question. Two different technologies with different purpose, two different platforms, different languages, etc.

Comment: you should read some introductory text on both frameworks first...

Comment: sorry for the bad question, I had tried to read some intro text before posting this, unfortunately it looks like I need a 'for dummies' explanation of the different purposes of these two, and their implications in terms of making a web service.

Comment: I actually thought this was an interesting question. RoR is heavily influenced by REST princples, and WCF now has a REST toolkit that .Net developers are using to make web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking at this the wrong way. What does the web service do?

The fact that it's a web service a mobile device talks to is itself not a big deal. Lots of stuff exists to do that. WCF is pretty good at it. I don't know anything about RoR but it probably is too.

So once the mobile device makes a request, what's going to happen on the server? Who is building it, and what languages/frameworks do they already know? What if any infrastructure is already in place?

If you can answer those questions, I think the answer to your question will become more apparent. :)

Comment: Thank-you for the advice! The main function of the server is data storage, and the service will handle data synchronization. The people building it don't have either skillsets, though they know .NET, python, c++, and as far as infrastructure - none in place.

Comment: If they already know .NET then they're halfway home with WCF. Just picking up the necessary WCF to provide a web service interface isn't a big deal.

Comment: Okay, yeah they'll probably go with that then, but was curious to know if using RoR would have more benefits over WCF to warrant learning something new and using that instead.